# j2objc:how to build libjunit.a for architecture i386

Tags: xcode4

when i linked the libjunit provided by the generated j2objc source code, and i try to build my project, this error is occured:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Niangsou/Documents/Workspace/mastercard/iOS/Mobile_api_Tests/SDKConversion/j2objc/lib/libjunit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/Niangsou/Documents/Workspace/mastercard/iOS/Mobile_api_Tests/SDKConversion/j2objc/lib/libjunit.a
>   and Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JunitFrameworkAssert", referenced from

How can I do to resolve this problem?
It seems that the `libjunit.a` generated is not supported by the arch i386.

Answer (score 1):

j2objc now distributes a libjunit.a that supports the armv7, armv7s, i386, MACOSX architectures.